# What order does the country name sort by in Chinese?

Tags: place-names

I'm quite confused to see how the country name is sorted in Chinese.

The pictures below are names of countries that show at the first and last of the total list. Ignore China and its administrative regions since it automatically puts them at the top of the list from my country settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Who sorted the list?

Comment: Don't bet on this order. Internationalise website simply sort the countries according to ISO country code, that is easier to maintain in various language.

Comment: @fefe It's on Twitter. I tried to add my phone number to verify the account, and the UI got me the list to pick up a country code. But I think the order is similar, if not the same, across any websites.

Comment: @Blaszard,You can check the method in this order: by Pinyin, by the number of strokes, by English alphabet, by country code, they are not sorted.

Comment: @Jacob So is it not consistent?

Comment: Jacob posted it before he learned the list is sorted by radicals order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by radical.

不 belongs to 一 radical (#1) therefore listed first

黑 belongs to 黑 radical: (#203) therefore listed last

If the first characters are the same, the radicals of the second characters will be ranked

Comment: Thanks. It looks so daunting! Do Chinese people have a full command of this radical order?

Comment: As a Chinese, I have never know there is  radical-sorting before, that is only can be done by computer surely. Nobody want to sort it mannualy. And it makes no sense obviously, who the hell know the order?.

Comment: I agree it is not practical to expect ordinary people to remember radical order. You need to know which radical a character  belongs to. The radical has less stokes would be listed higher than the ones with more stokes. If two radicals have the same number of stokes, you have to know which stoke order is ranked higher. You can only estimate, but knowing Chinese do help. For example, you know #112 石 is five stokes radical, and 
#85 氵(water) is three stokes radical, therefore, all 石 radical characters are listed lower than all 氵radical character.

Comment: The practical way to use radical sorting order,  is consult the radical order list, which is in the index of a all Chinese dictionaries.